# Add callback function when close a DockingPanel

Tags: autodesk-forge

I'm trying to add a callback function when a user close a DockingPanel by clicking on the cross :

[image]

I've take a to the documentation  but I do not see how to do this. I've found how to [create another button](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v5/reference/javascript/dockingpanel/)  for close my DockingPanel but nothing on the closing event on the click on the cross in the right corner...

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's quite simple, you can just add a few lines to archive it:

```
dockpanel.addVisibilityListener(function( show ) {
   if( show ) {
     // Logic for opening the panel
   } else {
     // Logic for closing the panel
   }
});
```

Reference: https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v5/reference/javascript/dockingpanel/

Answer (score 0):

A different way to do this :

```
initDock = () => {
   // open the panel
   this.dock = new Autodesk.Viewing.UI.DockingPanel(
      this.viewer.container,
      'dock_panel',
      'Room Properties',
    )

    this.dock.closer.onclick = () => {
      //
      // this can be your call back on close stuff
      //
      this.buttonAddBox.setState(false)
      this.buttonAddBox.removeClass('button-add-box__active')
      this.dock.uninitialize()
    }

    this.dock.setVisible(true)
}
```